# Android removal of options from one adapter changes the other

Tags: java, android

So I'm having an odd issue and I don't quite know why it is happening.

I have 2 spinners that have almost the same data in each.

So here's how I create the adapters:

```
ArrayList<String> resourceSoldOptions = new ArrayList<String>();
resourceSoldOptions.addAll(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.trade_calc_resource_names)));

ArrayList<String> resourceBoughtOptions = resourceSoldOptions;

final ArrayAdapter<String> resourceSoldAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, resourceSoldOptions);
final ArrayAdapter<String> resourceBoughtAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, resourceBoughtOptions);
```

And set the data for the spinners:

```
resourceSoldSpinner.setAdapter(resourceSoldAdapter);
resourceBoughtSpinner.setAdapter(resourceBoughtAdapter);
```

Then, I have a listener (`onItemSelectedListener`) that will change out the options of the bought spinner depending on the selection of the sold spinner

Here is how I go about that:

```
resourceSoldSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        //Get the resource chosen
        String resourceChosen = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

        //And remove the option from the bought options
        resourceBoughtAdapter.remove(resourceChosen);
        resourceBoughtAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});
```

But for some reason reason, the sold spinner is being affected, when there is no code to even suggest that it should be changed.

Am I going about this the wrong way? That seems likely, seen options will need to be constantly add/removed depending on choices.

Comment: `resourceBoughtOptions = resourceSoldOptions;` you are using the same list to back both adapters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that both `resourceBoughtOptions` and `resourceSoldOptions` are using the same ArrayList object.

When you create the bought list, you do it like so:

```
ArrayList<String> resourceBoughtOptions = resourceSoldOptions;
```

You never initialize `resourceBoughtOptions` to a new ArrayList instance- you are declaring that it is the same list as `resourceSoldOptions`. Thus you really just made two names for the same list.

The easiest fix would be to do this:

```
ArrayList<String> resourceBoughtOptions  = new ArrayList<String>();
resourecBoughtOptions.addAll(resourceSoldOptions);
```

This will actually create a new list for `resourceBoughtOptions` and copy all of the items from `resourceSoldOptions`.

Comment: Probably should have listened to IntelliJ when it flagged that code... Anywho, thanks for your help.